# Different representations of a decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

I'm seeing a difference in the behavior between the emulator in Visual Studio and my Lumia 820 when trying to parse a double. If I have a string which represent `string stringdouble = 3.434233`, the emulator correctly parses it to the corresponding double value, but on my Lumia 820 in debug mode, I have to replace the dot with a comma for it to work. What is causing this difference?

Comment: what I understand here is, nokia lumia is converting your string represented number as 3,434233 instead of 3.434233. If it is so, please respond so I can edit the question properly

Comment: I guess it's something connected with phone location settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a culture problem.

Your simulator and phone **probably have different cultures set up**, that's why you have differences in results. Use device or invariant culture.

I would recommend to either use **invariant culture** everywhere

```
double.Parse("3.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or **current users culture**

```
double number = Double.Parse("202.667,40", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

for both parsing and translating numbers to strings, this will help to avoid bugs you described

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer :-)